# When using node.js & Express why does extra / in address break link to image but not html file?

Tags: node.js, express

The following test code works as expected when **http://localhost:3000/test** is entered in the address bar.

This is from app.js

```
app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
});

app.use(express.static("public"));
```

This is from index.html

```
<img src="images/cat.jpg">
```

However when I enter **http://localhost:3000/test/** (note the extra `/` at the end) in the address bar index.html is served but the cat.jpg image shows up as a broken link.

I'm probably missing a fundamental concept but I don't understand why the extra `/` breaks the image link but index.html is still served.  Why doesn't it break them both or neither?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of how the browser resolves the URLs.  Your first URL, when the browser looks to fetch the image, will resolve to http://localhost:3000/images/cat.jpg, because the original URL ends as a resource `/test`.

The second version of the URL you're ending it as a directory `/test/` and so the resolved URL for the image will be http://localhost:3000/test/images/cat.jpg.

Comment: But why doesn't index.html also break?  It's sitting in `http://localhost:3000/public/` not  `http://localhost:3000/public/test/`.  Or maybe a different question, express is looking for `/test` but it serves index.html on `/test/` as well but with the broken cat.jpg link.  Why would it do that?

Comment: You’re confusing the URL path with the file path. Your first route you’ve shown here maps /test to a function which plucks the index file from the correct location in the file system and serves it when the URL that matches the path /test is hit. /test and /test/ both match, so both hit that same route handler.